# Add custom tax value at woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, fee

I want to add custom % value at woocommerce checkout page, but I want to show it only for Swiss country and hide it for others. Now I have the right code working for that, but the problems is that Im not able to show it when user choose switzerland. Here is a code so please help me see what Im doing wrong here

```
//Add tax for CH country
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
global $woocommerce;

if ( WC()->customer->get_shipping_country('CH') )
    return;

    $percentage = 0.08;
    $taxes = array_sum($woocommerce->cart->taxes);
    $surcharge = ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total + $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total ) * $percentage;   
    // Make sure that you return false here.  We can't double tax people!
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'TAX', $surcharge, false, '' );

}
```

Im sure Im doing wrong inside here:

```
if ( WC()->customer->get_shipping_country('CH') )
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **`WC_Customer`** **`get_shipping_country()`** doesn't accept any **country code** as you are getting a country code. So you need to set it differently in your code condition.

Also as your hooked function has already the WC_Cart object as argument, you don't need global `$woocommerce` and `$woocommerce->cart`…

So your revisited code should be:

```
// Add tax for Swiss country
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','custom_tax_surcharge_for_swiss', 10, 1 );
function custom_tax_surcharge_for_swiss( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined('DOING_AJAX') ) return;

    // Only for Swiss country (if not we exit)
    if ( 'CH' != WC()->customer->get_shipping_country() ) return;

    $percent = 8;
    # $taxes = array_sum( $cart->taxes ); // <=== This is not used in your function

    // Calculation
    $surcharge = ( $cart->cart_contents_total + $cart->shipping_total ) * $percent / 100;

    // Add the fee (tax third argument disabled: false)
    $cart->add_fee( __( 'TAX', 'woocommerce')." ($percent%)", $surcharge, false );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

Tested and works… you will get something like:

[image]

---

> But for taxes, you should better use default WooCommerce tax feature in *Settings > Tax (tab)*, where con can set the tax rates for each country…