# I am trying to setup default VAT on my WooCommerce site

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, fee

I am trying to make default VAT from Germany even users not login and after login, VAT will be according to there country code.

I am using *[Add custom tax value at woocommerce checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379965/add-custom-tax-value-at-woocommerce-checkout/47381973#47381973)* answer code.

Comment: This doesn't look like JS. Did you mean to tag PHP?

Comment: yes, I need this for Woocommerce.

Comment: What is the problem? Please edit your question as for instance there is no question. You should better use WooCommerce Tax settings.

Comment: yes but WooCommerce setting not providing by default VAT without choosing any country or any region. I believe if you have any solution please let me know.