# Woocommerce update cart total tax - woocommerce_after_calculate_totals

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Within my shop I had to adjust the calculation of the total cart value which was successfull. For this task I used `add_action( 'woocommerce_after_calculate_totals', 'custom_woocommerce_after_calculate_totals', 30 );`.

After my calculations I get for example a price of 167,74€ which includes 27,951... VAT (20%).
Now I have the problem that VAT calculation is wrong after a few digits.
The correct result should be 27,956... => rounded up to 27,96. Which results in a cent difference.

Because of the wrong value I tried to do my own calculation by "reverse engineering" the tax rate and calculating the tax_total on my own.

**My calculation:**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_calculate_totals', 'custom_woocommerce_after_calculate_totals', 30 );

function custom_woocommerce_after_calculate_totals( $cart ) {

    $subtotal = 0.0;
    /* Get cart items */
    $items = $cart->cart_contents;

    $do_one_time = 0;
    foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
    
        // Reverse engineer the tax rate because Woocommerce lacks a get rate method on the cart
        if($item['line_total'] && $item['line_tax']){
            if($do_one_time < 1){
                $the_cost = $item['line_total'];
                $the_tax = $item['line_tax'];
                $tax_rate = round(ceil(($the_tax / $the_cost)*1000)/1000,2);
                $do_one_time++;
            }
        }
        /* Calculate cart total value */
        if($item["line_subtotal"]){
            /* manually add up the cart item subtotal value and round it by 2 digits */
            $number = round($item["line_subtotal"], 2);
            $subtotal += $number;
        }

    }
    /* If shipping is set add it to subtotal value otherwise keep the already calculated subtotal*/
    if($cart->shipping_total){
        $subtotal_with_shipping = $cart->shipping_total + $subtotal;
        $subtotal_tax = $subtotal_with_shipping * $tax_rate;
        $total_cost = round($subtotal_with_shipping + $subtotal_tax, 2);
    }else{
        $subtotal_tax = $subtotal * $tax_rate;
        $total_cost = round($subtotal + $subtotal_tax, 2);
    }


    /* Compare cart total value with pre-calculated total value by woocommerce */
    /* If a difference within the values is present we update the total value with our own total value => $total_cost */

    if($subtotal !== $cart->subtotal_ex_tax){
        $cart->total = $total_cost;
    }    
    /* part which is not working */
    $cart->tax_total = $subtotal_tax;
    
    /* Also tried the following which changes the data within the cart but not on the frontend -> I saw the changes within var_dump($cart)*/
    $cart->set_total_tax($subtotal_tax);
    

}
```

Within my `$subtotal_tax` I have the correct value of 27,96€ but I can´t find a way to update the value.

For the total value I set the `$cart->total = $total_cost;` which worked fine.
I tried the same for the total tax with `$cart->tax_total = $subtotal_tax;` but I won´t change the value.

Is there some way to update the tax_total wihthin the `woocommerce_after_calculate_totals` action?

Output (Wrong): 
Total: 167,74€ which includes VAT of 27,95€ (20%).

Output (Needed):
Total: 167,74€ which includes VAT of 27,96€ (20%).

Comment: Did you try this ? - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/339000/woocommerce-rounding-cart-totals-with-tax-up

Comment: @MartinMirchev thanks for the tip but the rounding itself is not a problem.
I programmatically changed the cart total value but it won´t auto change the related vat of the total value. I have to find a way to change the vat of the total value within my action. Edit: and the checkbox is already unticked as mentioned on the other site.

Comment: I think this is the proper hook - woocommerce_calculate_totals where you have $cart object so it  should be add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','custom_woocommerce_after_calculate_totals', 10, 1 ); Also this is ajax so check those examples - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54427950/change-cart-total-using-hooks-in-woocommerce-3-2/54428561#54428561 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415783/change-cart-total-price-in-woocommerce/43416407#43416407 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379965/add-custom-tax-value-at-woocommerce-checkout