# How to add an additional amount in between specific total cart values Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shopping-cart

I need to add an amount to the woocommerce cart total value But in between a certain total amounts.

Ex: Need to add Rs. 250/= additional amount to the total only if the cart value is more than Rs. 2000/= and not more than Rs. 5000/=

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379965/add-custom-tax-value-at-woocommerce-checkout modify it to your needs

Comment: Thanks Martin Mirchev. The code below worked.

Comment: Glad u solved it out :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Thought someone may need it. This adds 199 to the total if the cart total value is more than 2000 and less than 5000.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'custom_fee_based_on_cart_total', 10, 1 );
function custom_fee_based_on_cart_total( $cart ) {

if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

// Additional Amount
$amount = 199;

// The cart total
$cart_total = $cart->cart_contents_total; 

// The conditional Calculation
// 2000 and 5000 is the effective price range
$fee = ($cart_total >= 2000 AND $cart_total <= 5000) ? $amount / 1 : 0;

if ( $fee != 0 ) 
    $cart->add_fee( __( "Additional Shipping", "woocommerce" ), $fee, false );
}
```